# Unable to start solr on windows

Tags: windows, solr

I have installed solr on my machine in C drive and when I run the command ***bin\solr.cmd start*** it returns the below error:

binsolr.cmd: command not found

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently using a shell that uses `\` for escaping letters.

Use `bin/solr.cmd` in that case, or use the old `cmd` console shell instead.